# How do I solve the problem of displaying accuracy parameter in CNN?

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network, detection, faster-rcnn

I'm facing a problem while computing accuracy parameter and sketching it in a graph.

I was expecting a drawn accuracy and loss graphs. In line:

```py
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I've tried changing `metrics=['accuracy']` to `metrics=['acc']` without any success.

This is the code:

```py
# Input layer
inputs = Input(shape=(img_dims, img_dims, 3))

# First conv block
x = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
x = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

# Second conv block
x = SeparableConv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = SeparableConv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

# Third conv block
x = SeparableConv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = SeparableConv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)

# Fourth conv block
x = SeparableConv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = SeparableConv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = Dropout(rate=0.2)(x)

# Fifth conv block
x = SeparableConv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = SeparableConv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
x = Dropout(rate=0.2)(x)

# FC layer
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(units=512, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(rate=0.7)(x)
x = Dense(units=128, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(rate=0.5)(x)
x = Dense(units=64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(rate=0.3)(x)

# Output layer
output = Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

# Creating model and compiling
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Callbacks
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='best_weights.hdf5', save_best_only=True,    save_weights_only=True)
lr_reduce = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.3, patience=2, verbose=2, mode='max')
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.1, patience=1, mode='min')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 3))
ax = ax.ravel()

for i, met in enumerate(['acc']):
    ax[i].plot(hist.history[met])
    ax[i].plot(hist.history['val_' + met])
    ax[i].set_title('Model {}'.format(met))
    ax[i].set_xlabel('epochs')
    ax[i].set_ylabel(met)
    ax[i].legend(['train', 'val'])
```

This is the error:

```
KeyError:'acc'
```

Comment: Hi, did you add `model.fit()' in the implementation? If not, please refer: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/cnn#:~:text=history%20%3D%20model.fit(train_images%2C%20train_labels%2C%20epochs%3D10%2C%20%0A%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20%C2%A0%20validation_data%3D(test_images%2C%20test_labels))

Comment: are you trying to show the plot on real time while training the network?

Comment: I'm trying to display the accuracy of the training model by scanning chest x-rays for detecting pneumonia

Comment: # Fitting the model
hist = model.fit_generator(
           train_gen, steps_per_epoch=train_gen.samples // batch_size, 
           epochs=epochs, validation_data=test_gen, 
           validation_steps=test_gen.samples // batch_size, callbacks=[checkpoint, lr_reduce])

Comment: That's how I fit the model